# override a column in trigger sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables for example Employee and a history table called EmployeeHistory. Both tables are the same, the difference is the column EmployeeHistoryId on EmployeeHistory table.

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
(
EmployeeId INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
FirstName NVARCHAR(128),
LastName NVARCHAR(128),
ModifiedDate datetimeoffset
)

CREATE TABLE EmployeeHistory
(
EmployeeHistoryId INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
EmployeeId INT,
FirstName NVARCHAR(128),
LastName NVARCHAR(128),
ModifiedDate datetimeoffset
)
```

I have a trigger that actually copy the record from Employee to EmployeeHistory after any update, insert or delete.

Suppose we are doing un update on Employee table, we use a stored procedure called EmployeeUpdate, in that sp we force the ModifiedDate = SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() so the history table will have the same record in sync with the ModifiedDate.

What if someone do un update like this outside the sp:

```
UPDATE Employee SET FirstName = 'John' where EmployeeId = 1
```

In this case we are not touching the ModifiedDate, so in the trigger if this column wasn't updated I force the insert in the history table with ModifiedDate = SYSDATETIMEOFFSET().
The problem with this is that the original table will have a different ModifiedDate that is not in sync with the history.

Should I override the ModifiedDate in the Employee table even if the user didn't update it? What's the best approach for this case? I know everyone should use the sp but...

Comment: You could have trigger on the table that will updated `ModifiedDate` with when ever records are updated. That will be the only way to avoid someone manually updating the table and your SP not setting the value.

Comment: In the trigger, you can compare `ModifiedDate` between the `inserted` and `deleted` virtual tables, then decide how to proceed if they match/don't match.  Normally, I'd do this type of logic within a `FOR UPDATE` trigger (not insert/delete).

Comment: but doing this it will not create a kind of circular reference between the update and the update inside the trigger?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "circular reference" in this context.

Comment: I'm updating ModifiedDate column of the original table inside the trigger, so this will cause the trigger to fire again...

Comment: I think that would depend on whether or not recursive triggers are enabled for the database.  Recursion can be tricky.  I would look at an `INSTEAD OF UPDATE` trigger before trying to deal with trigger recursion.